# About The Sum of Positive Divisors of $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

The question says:

> Find the smallest positive integer $n$ so that $\sigma(x)=n$ has no solution, exactly two solutions, exactly three solutions.

I could not come up with a good way to solve this question other that trial and error. But I am questioning this method. Is there any better ideas?

Comment: I think brute search is optimal, if a bit tedious.  You'll find the answer fairly quickly.

Comment: Oh, thanks, my method sounds good though.

Comment: Absolutely, yes.  And you are  correct about $2,12$.  The third part won't take you as long as you fear.  Keep in mind $\sigma_1(n)≥n+1$ with equality only for primes.  That makes it easy to truncate your search.

Comment: found it to be 24?

Comment: Correct again. $\,$

Comment: Thanks for your help @lulu

Comment: If you are so inclined, you might want to post your calculations as a solution.  Keeps the question from being listed as unanswered.

Comment: @lulu, just done so and edited the question details to be convenient.

Comment: (+1) for the posted solution, good work.

Comment: Thanks,, I really appreciate  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By trial and error, I have found that the solutions are:

- $\sigma(x) = 2$   has no solution.
- $\sigma(x) = 12$  has exactly two solutions that are $6$ and $11$.
- $\sigma(x) = 24$  has exactly three solutions that are $14,15$ and $23$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of divisors of a natural number $n$ is given by $\sigma(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left ( \left \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right \rfloor-\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right \rfloor \right )$.

This may be useful when expanding the summation.

Note that, when $n$ is a prime number, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left ( \left \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right \rfloor-\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right \rfloor \right )=2$

Comment: how did you come up with this formula?

Comment: $\sigma(n)$ is not the number of divisors function.